# How to make TabbedPannel's tabs fill all horizontal space?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating a simple app interface using kivy and the kv language. The interface consists of a search text input, a button for search confirmation and an 'add' button. Bellow this, there is a `TabbedPanel` for the app's contents:

```
#:import label kivy.uix.label
#:import sla kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter

<MenuScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint_y: 0.15
                TextInput:
                    text: 'Search'

                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 0.2
                    text: 'Ok'
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 0.2
                    text: '+'
            TabbedPanel:
                do_default_tab: False

                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'tab1'
                    ListView:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        adapter:
                            sla.SimpleListAdapter(
                            data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)],
                            cls=label.Label)
                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'tab2'
                    BoxLayout:
                        Label:
                            text: 'Second tab content area'
                        Button:
                            text: 'Button that does nothing'
                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'tab3'
                    RstDocument:
                        text:
                            '\\n'.join(("Hello world", "-----------",
                            "You are in the third tab."))
```

This is the design output:

[image: kivy regular app interface]

The `TabbedPannel` works perfectly the way I desire, however I want the tabs to fill all the horizontal space. For instance, if I use a `BoxLayout` with `Button`s, they expand using all the horizontal space, just as I want it:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    Button:
        text: 'tab1'
    Button:
        text: 'tab2'
    Button:
        text: 'tab3'
```

[image: Horizontal BoxLayout buttons]

Is there a way to tune the `TabbedPannel` so its `TabbedPannelItem`s tabs can use all the horizontal space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `tab_width` property of `TabbedPanel` to its width divided by number of tabs:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: self.size[0]/len(self.tab_list)
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab 1'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab3'
""")

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```